# Correct way to poll an API every minute until a max in Java within a test framework

Tags: java, testng, timertask

I want to regular poll (not long poll) an API using TimerTask from inside an integration test. Basically, I want to poll every minute, and if 15 minutes have passed, I want to stop polling and fail my test.

I haven't done this before, so I'm looking into different ways of doing this. One simple idea I have is just doing a for loop 15 times. Each iteration, I call the API, check the response, and if it's not what I expect, wait 1 minute using `Thread.sleep()` Here is sample code for it:

```
@Test
public void testHappyPath() {
    SomeApiRequest request = ...;
    SomeApiResponse response;
    for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 15; attempt++) {
                
                response = client
                        .getResult(request);
                // perform conditional logic on response
                if (response.hasItemIWant()) {
                    Assert.assertTrue(<certain things about response>);
                    return;
                }
                Thread.sleep(60000);
    }
    Assert.fail("Did not receive the expected response within 15 minutes.");
}
```

What I'm concerned about here is that since I have multiple tests that will do similar logic and also have Thread.sleep(), I am not sure what if any byproducts of that there are. I am using TestNG as my framework, and I believe TestNG runs tests in parallel. If it does, I am hoping that doing Thread.sleep() only affects the thread for that specific test.

I have also looked into TimerTask. The problem I have found with this though is that it seems like if I want to have an upper limit on retries (like I have 15 in the above example), I will still need the loop anyway. Plus, it is not trivial to return a value from a timer task, so I would need to check the response within the TimerTask object itself. I can't declare the response object outside of the timer task and use it within the timer task unless response is a final or class variable, which doesn't work for my case. I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
@Test
public void testHappyPath() {
    SomeApiRequest request = ...;
    boolean allAssertionsPassed = false;
    Timer t = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt = TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SomeApiResponse response = client.getResult(request);
            if (response.hasItemIWant()) {
                Assert.assertTrue(<some things about response>);
                allAssertionsPassed = true;
                t.cancel();
            }
        };
    };
    for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 15; attempt++) {
        // fixed delay scheduling. run every minute but in case a call takes super long
        // for some reason multiple calls won't happen at the same time.
        t.schedule(tt, 0, 60000);
        if (allAssertionsPassed) {
            return;
        }
    }
    Assert.fail("Did not receive the expected response within 15 minutes.");
}
```

I'm not sure if the above code is correct, and again I don't quite know what would happen if these tests are run in parallel.

What is the correct way of doing this? I have not done this before so an example would be helpful.

Comment: For tests, I recommend the library Awaitility, it provides all the mechanisms that you require, in a nice API.  But besides, Thread.sleep is also ok, it does not have negative effects outside the current thread. If you have hundreds of threads, then sleep wastes quite some resources, but this is usually not the case for test runs.

Comment: @jhyot do you know if tests are run in parallel, does testng spin up separate threads for each, and in that case, does doing Thread.sleep cause any issues?

Comment: It depends on the test framework or runner. It must be either in separate threads or in separate processes. In either case, Thread.sleep should not cause any issues, because the tests must be independent of each other anyways to be able to run in parallel.